# Blank fragments on application restart

Tags: android, android-fragments

Whenever I open my application for the first time, there are three fragments displayed correctly in 3 containers I have in my xml file. Upon clicking a tab on the action bar, one of the containers' fragment is swapped for another.

## The Problem

Whenever I open the app, swap to the second tab, use the back arrow to exit the app, then reopen the app and re-select the second tab, the fragment is blank. Nothing appears, and the same problem occurs with the third tab also. Why aren't the second and third fragments being displayed?

Comment: Show us your code (specifically your back method and onresume but also other things that you feel are important)

Comment: @AndroidPenguin I managed to solve my problem, but I appreciate the help all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using  a `public static boolean started` value in each of my fragments. In each fragment's class, in the `onCreateView()` I set `started = true;` and in the `onDestroyView()` I set `started = false;`
In the `onTabSelected()` method of my main activity, I read this `boolean` value, and if it is `true`, I attach the fragment back to its container, but if it is `false`, I create a new instance of the particular fragment and add it to the container.

Comment: It's good that you got it working; please accept your own answer. But still, it doesn't look like you are implementing the Tabs and fragments properly. You need to pass add a fragment with a tag and later receive the fragment by tag. Check my answer below to see one way of properly implementing tabs, or technically, properly setting the ActionBar navigation mode to Tabs.

Comment: That's exactly how I implement the tabs. Using your method,the fragments load like normal, but I still have the same problem occur where the fragments aren't appearing on the second launch unless I remove the app from "Recent Applications".

Answer (score 1):

```
// from onCreate() method of your DefaultActivity class, call this method:

// file: DefaultActivity.java

...
...
...
    private void addTabs() {
        // get support ActionBar and set navigation mode to Tabs
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Add first tab to ActionBar, and set the TabListener to a new TabListner object
        String title1 = "first_tab";
        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = bar.newTab();
        tab1.setText(title1);
        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, title1, Fragment1.class));
        bar.addTab(tab1);

        // Add second tab to ActionBar, and set the TabListener to a new TabListner object
        String title2 = "second_tab";
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = bar.newTab();
        tab2.setText(locationsTitle);
        tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, tab2, Fragment2.class));
        bar.addTab(tab2);

        // Add third tab to ActionBar, and set the TabListener to a new TabListner object
        String title3 = "third_tab";
        ActionBar.Tab tab3 = bar.newTab();
        tab3.setText(title3);
        tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(this, title3, Fragment3.class));
        bar.addTab(tab3);
    }
... 
...
...
```

Now, you need to crate three fragments - Fragment1, Fragment2, and Fragment3 as well as create a TabListener:

```
// file: TabListener.java

public class TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class mFragmentClass;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class fragmentClass) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mFragmentClass = fragmentClass;
        // see if we already have the fragment with given tag. it's okay if it is null
        mFragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // instantiate a new fragment for the given class
            mFragment = SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mFragmentClass.getName());
            // place in the default root viewgroup - android.R.id.content
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            if (mFragment.isDetached())
                ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

That's all you need.